Telethon Searching empty results handle
I'm trying to use search function with iter_messages(search_channel, search=foo) and do not know how to handle when no results are found.
This is not an error, it is just a valid zero results. My expectation was that .total=None will do the job, but somehow not. When I run debug, than see .total is set to None regardless of messages were found or not, only when it goes down to the for loop .total will have correct not None value.
My code is:
def downloader():
    client.start()
    allFoundMessages=client.iter_messages(search_channel, search=search_line_update())
    if allFoundMessages.total is not None:                                                                                                 
        for message in allFoundMessages:
            print(message.id, message.text, '\n\n###\n')
            break
    else:
        print("Could not find anything by:", search_line_update(), "in:", search_channel )
        exit(0)

My expectation is that I can use total to determine if there are any results in a search or not.
